# Yocto Bitbake Fails with WSL2

Tags: yocto

I have a windows10 machine with WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm following the instructions at http://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html  it all goes well until I try to run bitbake - I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to start bitbake server (None)
ERROR: Server log for this session (/mnt/c/Users/geoff/poky/build/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log):
75 13:01:41.843148 --- Starting bitbake server pid 75 at 2021-06-16 13:01:41.843127 ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/geoff/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake-server", line 53, in <module>
    bb.server.process.execServer(lockfd, readypipeinfd, lockname, sockname, timeout, xmlrpcinterface)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/geoff/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/server/process.py", line 538, in execServer
    sock.bind(os.path.basename(sockname))
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

Does anyone here know how to get around / fix this problem?

Comment: permission issues?

Answer (score 2):

I've played around with this for a bit and have it working. I think the problem was that poky was installed on the windows directory /mnt/c/Users/geoff/poky  I changed this to ~/poky and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the project to any not-shared folder solves this issue.
As suggested, ~/ it's a good option.